# What is the purpose of andFilterWhere() 2nd operand in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I've searched the information and checked the documentation according to this, but it's still not clear to me what `andFilterWhere()` condition 2nd operand does.

According to the documentation, it says:

> operand 2 be a string or an array representing the values that the column or DB expression should be like. For example, ['like', 'name', 'tester']

But it's still not clear to me. Could someone explain me more about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use it as a 3 elements array:

```
['like', 'name', 'tester']
```

- First param `like` is operand, which will be used in query to create
  `like` query (it can be `=`, `!=` etc.)
- Second param `name` is column name in your DB table.
- Third param is value to compare, for example user input.

If you use it as key => value:

```
['name' => $this->name]
```

- Key `name` is column name in your DB table
- Value `$this->name` is property of your model, where youre holding
  user input.